# Where I can find the exact time when a certain company's stock will be available in the secondary market?

Tags: united-states, stocks, ipo

As mentioned in title, I want to know when we can buy an IPO stock in the secondary market. Such as I want to buy stock in Twitter as soon as it is provided in the secondary market.

I googled for a long time, but I found no site would provide a list to show the exact time of recent IPO offerings in the secondary market.

Not limited to Twitter, is there a site that publishes the public trading time of all IPO stock?  It would be very convenient to know when in order to buy the stock as early as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter is planning to go public on NYSE. You'll be able to start trading once the stock is listed for trading, which would be the day of the IPO.

Note that since you're trading on the *secondary* market, you won't be able to buy at the IPO prices, whatever the time is. You're buying *from* someone who bought at IPO price.

Comment: But no site give a exact time that when twitter would be provided in secondary market.

Comment: the day of the IPO? I just can't get it,is it the day IPO completed?

Comment: @Mithril the exact time hasn't been announced yet.

Comment: so,where I can see the exact time if it be published? Not limited to twitter, is there a site publish the  public trading time of all IPO stock ?

Comment: @Mithril for US stocks - SEC.

Comment: I have browsed `http://www.sec.gov/` for 10 min , but nothing relevent found.

Comment: Look for S1 filings. But I'd suggest to look for press-releases. Much easier to find and read. If you expect to find the information about twitter now - you won't.

Answer (score 0):

Very often, the word `secondary market` is used synonymously with the `stock market` as we all know it.

In this case, the `primary market` would be the "closed" world of VCs, business angels, etc to which stock market investors do not have access, e.g. the securities are not trading on a public stock market.